# Using react-dates with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-dates

I am trying to use `react-dates` with Typescript, but cannot figure out how to define the types.

The following TS/React code is giving the error

> Argument of type '"startDate" | "endDate" | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
> Type '"startDate"' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction'.

My code is [based on this](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/2025#issuecomment-660970851), is there a simplier way to write this code? Thank you!

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import moment from 'moment';
import "react-dates/initialize";
import "react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css";
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates';

interface IHandleDatesChange {
    startDate: moment.Moment | null,
    endDate: moment.Moment | null,
}

export function Foo(): JSX.Element {
    const [ startDate, setStartDate ] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(moment('1990-01-01'));
    const [ endDate, setEndDate ] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(moment(moment().endOf('year')));
    const [ focusedInput, setFocusedInput ] = useState(null);

    const handleDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate}: IHandleDatesChange) => {
        setStartDate(startDate);
        setEndDate(endDate);
    }

    return (
        <DateRangePicker
            startDate={startDate}
            startDateId='daterangepicker_start_date'
            endDate={endDate}
            endDateId='daterangepicker_end_date'
            onDatesChange={handleDatesChange}
            focusedInput={focusedInput}
            onFocusChange={(focusedInput) => setFocusedInput(focusedInput)}   // <== ERROR OCCURS
        />
    )
}
```

---

**yarn.lock**

```
react-dates@^21.8.0:
  version "21.8.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-dates/-/react-dates-21.8.0.tgz#355c3c7a243a7c29568fe00aca96231e171a5e94"
  integrity sha512-PPriGqi30CtzZmoHiGdhlA++YPYPYGCZrhydYmXXQ6RAvAsaONcPtYgXRTLozIOrsQ5mSo40+DiA5eOFHnZ6xw==
  dependencies:
    airbnb-prop-types "^2.15.0"
    consolidated-events "^1.1.1 || ^2.0.0"
    enzyme-shallow-equal "^1.0.0"
    is-touch-device "^1.0.1"
    lodash "^4.1.1"
    object.assign "^4.1.0"
    object.values "^1.1.0"
    prop-types "^15.7.2"
    raf "^3.4.1"
    react-moment-proptypes "^1.6.0"
    react-outside-click-handler "^1.2.4"
    react-portal "^4.2.0"
    react-with-direction "^1.3.1"
    react-with-styles "^4.1.0"
    react-with-styles-interface-css "^6.0.0"

...

"@types/react-dates@^21.8.1":
  version "21.8.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react-dates/-/react-dates-21.8.1.tgz#f90b30895e22d15f42c64be6bbafb1796b5f05f8"
  integrity sha512-zgBf0SM6dcDPR29x3bCzSypK0c2+EKDkR4NNyBCwH2GyL/AgIvJ0bQ6n2z1s468SXS2QbzCMJtF831vG7iGkjg==
  dependencies:
    "@types/react" "*"
    "@types/react-outside-click-handler" "*"
    moment "^2.26.0"

...

moment@>=1.6.0, moment@^2.26.0, moment@^2.29.1:
  version "2.29.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/moment/-/moment-2.29.1.tgz#b2be769fa31940be9eeea6469c075e35006fa3d3"
  integrity sha512-kHmoybcPV8Sqy59DwNDY3Jefr64lK/by/da0ViFcuA4DH0vQg5Q6Ze5VimxkfQNSC+Mls/Kx53s7TjP1RhFEDQ==
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

You haven't passed a type to your `focusedInput` state. If you check the `@types/react-dates` definitions, the `onFocusChange` prop expects the callback argument to be a specific type: [`FocusedInputShape`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-dates/index.d.ts#L159) which is a string union `'startDate' | 'endDate'`.

To fix, update your state init:

```
const [ focusedInput, setFocusedInput ] = useState<FocusedInputShape | null>(null);
```

**Original answer:**

I seem to recall hitting this issue (or very similar) before and it turned out to be a `moment` version mismatch between the dependency installed in my project and the dependency installed by `react-dates`.

Check which versions are installed and if they do not match, up-/down-grade your project version if you can to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I've updated the question with the versions of `moment` and `react-dates`. Do you happen to recall the versions that you used when it worked for you?

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head but will check if I can find the old project. Is `moment` a dependency on your project? I would suggest ensuring you use the exact version listed in the `react-dates` deps ([2.29.1](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/master/package.json#L99)) and see if it helps at all. The community typings `@types/react-dates` also use a different version `2.26.0` which isn't ideal.

Comment: Thanks! Yes `moment@2.29.1` is a dependency of my project. I have tried downgrading to `@types/react-dates@21.8.0` while maintaining `react-dates@21.8.0`, still getting the same error. Wonder if there's something wrong with my Typescript code...

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? I think I've spotted the actual issue and it's not conflicting versions of `moment` - you need to pass a type to your `focusedInput` state. I'll update my answer with a suggested fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got the basic example to work with TS.

```
import React, { ReactNode, useState } from 'react'
import moment, { Moment } from 'moment'
import 'react-dates/initialize'
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css'
import { DateRangePicker, FocusedInputShape } from 'react-dates'

const Calendar = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Moment | null>(moment())
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState<Moment | null>(null)
  const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState<FocusedInputShape | null>(
    null
  )

  const handlendDatesChange = (arg: {
    startDate: Moment | null
    endDate: Moment | null
  }) => {
    setStartDate(arg.startDate)
    setEndDate(arg.endDate)
  }

  const handleFocusChange = (arg: FocusedInputShape | null) => {
    setFocusedInput(arg)
  }

  return (
    <DateRangePicker
      /**
       * Tip for who is new to TS: You can view the type definition on hover in VSCode.
       * You can use these types on their respective useState and function.
       */
      startDate={startDate} // moment.Moment | null;
      startDateId="your_unique_start_date_id" // moment.Moment | null;
      endDate={endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
      endDateId="your_unique_end_date_id" // string;
      onDatesChange={handlendDatesChange} // (arg: { startDate: moment.Moment | null; endDate: moment.Moment | null }) => void;
      focusedInput={focusedInput} // FocusedInputShape | null;
      onFocusChange={handleFocusChange} // (arg: FocusedInputShape | null) => void;
    />
  )
}

export default Calendar
```